# Can't install Sylius starter project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sylius

I'd like to create a Sylius project but I can't install the initial project following the instructions in the documentation.

the command compose

```
compose create-project sylius/sylius-standard MyFirstShop
```

works but when I create .env.local which contains  :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@localhost/my_project?serverVersion=8
```

then I run the command :
`php bin/console sylius:install` this is where the installation crashes.

I have the following error :

[image: no database error]

then I create the database on phpmyadmin then I re-run the command with the database created but empty:

[image]

I tried to launch the creation of the database with doctrine and then do the migration but still the same as the image above.

[image]

Someone who has already had the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

! UPDATE ! : I solved the problem by changing the php version to 8.0.30 !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).